# Deprecated: class-smtp.php is deprecated since version 5.5.0

Tags: php, wordpress, email, smtp

> Deprecated: class-smtp.php is deprecated since version 5.5.0! Use
> wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php instead. The SMTP class has been moved
> to the wp-includes/PHPMailer subdirectory and now uses the
> PHPMailer\PHPMailer namespace. in /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php
> on line 4963

Here is my code. Can any one help me to solve the issues?

```
<?php
defined('WYSIJA') or die('Restricted access');

require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-smtp.php';
class WYSIJA_MySMTP extends SMTP {
  public function StartTLS() {
    stream_context_set_option($this->smtp_conn, "ssl", "verify_peer", false);
    stream_context_set_option($this->smtp_conn, "ssl", "verify_peer_name", false);
    stream_context_set_option($this->smtp_conn, "ssl", "allow_self_signed", true);
    return parent::StartTLS();
  }
}
```